# Does eggplant support motion detect?

Tags: eggplant

I am trying to automate one of the applications wherein I have to check whether a video is getting played or not in full screen mode.I have to specifically check whether there is any motion happening during playback. Can anyone please help me here ? I tried taking multiple frames but it won't be an efficient way to do so as the frames will keep on changing depending on the video.

Thanks
Sanket.

Answer (score 0):

Eggplant doesn't currently have any built in support for motion detection. If you are only verifying that a video is playing you could check if the color has changed at some key points within the video rectangle.

```
set color1 = colorAtLocation(someLocationWithinVideoFrame)
wait 1
set color2 = colorAtLocation(someLocationWithinVideoFrame)

if color1 = color2 
    set videoPlaying = false
else 
    set videoPlaying = true
end if
```